# Sobolev's lemma on manifolds

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, sobolev-spaces

Let $M$ be a n-dimensional closed submanifold in $\mathbb{R}^m.$ I was looking for a version of Sobolev's lemma saying that for $f \in {W}^{k,2}$ we find a representative of $f \in C^{r}$ satisfying $k>r + \frac{n}{2}.$ Does this still hold for manifolds or is this no longer true in this context?

I should add that maybe the Sobolev lemma does not exactly hold in this version, but I assumed that this is the most probable one for it to hold.

Comment: Yes, this is true. For the n-torus (where one can use Fourier series) a proof is given in Theorem 5.7 of http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~aar/papers/roeindex.pdf The general case should be in many textbooks on global analysis.

Comment: You should do this for an abstract manifold yourself using a partition of unity.

Comment: This is done in Griffiths-Harris's book on Algebraic geometry, along the lines checked by ThiKu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This follows from its counterpart in the Euclidean space by local charts.

If you want to have an estimate on the derivative $D^r f$, then you should impose some bounds on derivatives of the curvature and a lower bound on the injectivity radius.